# Fetching data from SQLite and display them in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I'd like to fetch all the data from word column and display them on a UITableView.
I'm getting this error: **Fatal error: Index out of range.**
I'm aware of what the error means. The column has data. I'm not sure where is wrong.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! myCustomCell
    while 0 == willbeshown.count {
         cell.myLableCell1?.text = willbeshown[indexPath.row]
    }
    return cell
 }  

 var willbeshown:[String] = []

 @IBAction func findContact(_ sender: Any) {                      
      let contactDB = FMDatabase(path: databasesPath)
      if contactDB.open() {
      NSLog("DB open")
      let querySQL = "SELECT * FROM hehe"
      let result: FMResultSet? = contactDB.executeQuery(querySQL, withArgumentsIn: [])
      while result?.next() == true {
            if let appendeddata = result?.string(forColumn:"word") {
            willbeshown.append(appendeddata)
       }
    }

       tableview.reloadData()
       contactDB.close()
 }
```

Comment: What do you return from numberOfRowsInSection: function of your tableview?

Comment: Hopefully it's just `return willbeshown.count`.

Comment: Unrelated, but I'd suggest losing that `while 0 == willbeshown.count { ... }`. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Subramanian Mariappa@Rob thank you everyone. I removed while 0 == willbeshown.count { ... } and added willbeshown.count in the func(numberOfRowsInSection) it works without error but when I add data into the column and hit the findContact button, I see duplicated datas..I guess I'm doing wrong somewhere else. I'll take a look at other codes and ask a question about it if I can't figure out by myself.

Comment: Yep, that sounds like something else. I might suggest you just go ahead and delete this question...